# How to create a DOM element from a template?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Suppose I have a template saved in HTML and using standard underscore syntax.

My understanding is that I can grab the template using jQuery as such:

```
var html = $('#item-foo').html()
```

From there I can interpolate it using

```
var interpolated = _.template(html, {prop: "and_values"});
```

To create a DOM element in the JavaScript I can use this utility function

```
// converts HTML string to DOM object
Pub.HTMLToElement = function (html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    return div.firstChild;
};

var element = HTMLToElement(interpolated);
```

and finally I have my element in JavaScript which all began with a template in the HTML.

Is this the best way to do this?

It seemed long so I just wanted to validate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little bit simpler and you are already using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
Hello <%=name%>, how are you?
</script>
<div id="container" />
```

JS:

```
var str=$('#template').html();
var interpolated = _.template(str, {name: "pizza"});
$('#container').append($('<div/>').html(interpolated));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QAT4n/

Comment: what does `.html(interpolated)` do exactly

Comment: @user3294169: Have you read the [fine manual](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)?

Comment: @user3294169: it replaces the `innerHTML` of the object with `interpolated`. It is similar to doing `.innerHTML=` on a DOM element.  http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, jQuery automatically converts HTML to an element. This would be a shorter way:

```
var element = $(interpolated).get(0);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/get/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2

---

So the whole process would be like this:

```
var html = $('#item-foo').html()
var interpolated = _.template(html, {prop: "and_values"});
var element = $(interpolated).get(0);
```

And could be cleaned up to this:

```
var interpolated = _.template(
        $('#item-foo').html()
        , {
            prop: "and_values"
        });
var element = $(interpolated).get(0);
```